# Adaptive contrast enhancement

Tags: matlab, histogram

i need some help here.. how to create this application using matlab.. image enhancement using adaptive contrast enhancement.. this is the proposed method that i will follow..

The proposed method presented here uses HE in a controlled and localized manner to stretch the details in dark images while improving overall contrast in brighter ones. It is referred to as Adaptive Contrast Enhancement (ACE) because of the locally adaptive effect that is produced in each frame. The proposed algorithm begins by dividing the histogram of the luminance levels into three regions – dark, mid and bright. These regions were of equal size. Each of these three regions is then processed independently using HE. The effect of HE is then toned down depending on the shape of the histogram of each region.

Comment: Could you possibly show the code you have so far?